# Ordered Column Constrained Permutations Python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, multiple-columns

I have a question about doing permutations with an ordering constraint in python. For the problem an illustration of the issue may be best

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
1 | a | !
2 | b | @
3 | c | #
```

Now I would like to generate all possible permutations keeping the column ordering such that column 1, before column 2 before column 3, for N-columns

```
1-a-!
1-a-@
1-a-#
1-b-!
1-b-@
1-b-#
```

... etc

You can clearly do this by writing nested loops, but I was curious if there was a pythonic way to do this.

Comment: is the input stored in file???

Comment: it could be if needed, but for the sake of this lets assume it is already stored in memory using a framework like pandas where you have access to each column and its contents independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a Cartesian product, not permutations. For that, we have `itertools.product`.

```
import itertools

columns = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['!', '@', '#']
    ]

result = ['-'.join(thing) for thing in itertools.product(*columns)]
```

And so, we have `result`:

```
['1-a-!', '1-a-@', '1-a-#', '1-b-!', '1-b-@', '1-b-#', '1-c-!', '1-c-@', '1-c-#', 
 '2-a-!', '2-a-@', '2-a-#', '2-b-!', '2-b-@', '2-b-#', '2-c-!', '2-c-@', '2-c-#', 
 '3-a-!', '3-a-@', '3-a-#', '3-b-!', '3-b-@', '3-b-#', '3-c-!', '3-c-@', '3-c-#']
```

As you can see, `itertools.product` also preserves ordering within each argument, so that `!` precedes `@` precedes `#` and so forth, in case you also need that.

By the way, the `*` in `itertools.product(*columns)` is an [argument unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you. I appreciate the example as well. This is significantly cleaner than nested loops and the separation of each column into a list makes product a viable option again (since it would not work with all elements in one list)  
Not sure why I can't edit the above comment